# Implement a Mutex in OpenCL for Matrix Multiplication Example

Tags: synchronization, opencl, mutex, fpga

I am trying to implement a mutex for OpenCL Matrix Multiplication Example. The idea is to implement an instrumentation for every single individual add an item to be able to proceed atomically to print the number of multiplication. Currently, I implement a spinlock. The code for the kernel is

```
#include "../host/inc/matrixMult.h"
#ifndef SIMD_WORK_ITEMS
#define SIMD_WORK_ITEMS 4 // default value
#endif

__kernel
__attribute((reqd_work_group_size(BLOCK_SIZE,BLOCK_SIZE,1)))
__attribute((num_simd_work_items(SIMD_WORK_ITEMS)))
void matrixMult( // Input and output matrices
             __global float *restrict C,
             __global float *A,
             __global float *B,
             __global double *num,
             // Widths of matrices.
             int A_width, int B_width){
// Local storage for a block of input matrices A and B
__local float A_local[BLOCK_SIZE][BLOCK_SIZE];
__local float B_local[BLOCK_SIZE][BLOCK_SIZE];

// Block index
int block_x = get_group_id(0);
int block_y = get_group_id(1);

// Local ID index (offset within a block)
int local_x = get_local_id(0);
int local_y = get_local_id(1);

// Compute loop bounds
int a_start = A_width * BLOCK_SIZE * block_y;
int a_end   = a_start + A_width - 1;
int b_start = BLOCK_SIZE * block_x;

float running_sum = 0.0f;

// Compute the matrix multiplication result for this output element. Each
// loop iteration processes one block of the matrix.
for (int a = a_start, b = b_start; a <= a_end; a += BLOCK_SIZE, b += (BLOCK_SIZE * B_width))
{
    // Load the matrices to local memory. Note that the (x, y) indices
    // are swapped for A_local and B_local. This affects the reads from
    // A_local and B_local below and result in more efficient hardware.
    //
    // This is actually an optimization that the compiler can perform,
    // but is shown here for illustration purposes.
    A_local[local_y][local_x] = A[a + A_width * local_y + local_x];
    B_local[local_x][local_y] = B[b + B_width * local_y + local_x];

    // Wait for the entire block to be loaded.
    barrier(CLK_LOCAL_MEM_FENCE);

    // Do the dot product accumulation within this block. Fully unroll the loop.
    // As a result of the swap of indices above, memory accesses to
    // A_local and B_local are very efficient because each loop iteration
    // accesses consecutive elements. This can be seen by unrolling the
    // loop and analyzing the regions that are loaded:
    //  A_local[local_y][0..BLOCK_SIZE-1] and
    //  B_local[local_x][0..BLOCK_SIZE-1]

    #pragma unroll
   for (int k = 0; k < BLOCK_SIZE; ++k)
    {
    running_sum += A_local[local_y][k] * B_local[local_x][k];
   // Wait for the block to be fully consumed before loading the next
    // block.
    barrier(CLK_LOCAL_MEM_FENCE);
}

// Store result in matrix C
C[get_global_id(1) * get_global_size(0) + get_global_id(0)] = running_sum;
}
```

And I added the Mutex as the following

```
#include "../host/inc/matrixMult.h"
#ifndef SIMD_WORK_ITEMS
#define SIMD_WORK_ITEMS 4 // default value
#endif

__kernel
__attribute((reqd_work_group_size(BLOCK_SIZE,BLOCK_SIZE,1)))
__attribute((num_simd_work_items(SIMD_WORK_ITEMS)))
void matrixMult( // Input and output matrices
             __global float *restrict C,
             __global float *A,
             __global float *B,
             __global double *num,
             // Widths of matrices.
             int A_width, int B_width){
// Local storage for a block of input matrices A and B
__local float A_local[BLOCK_SIZE][BLOCK_SIZE];
__local float B_local[BLOCK_SIZE][BLOCK_SIZE];
// ///////////////////////
__local mutex;
mutex = 0;

// ////////////////////////

// Block index
int block_x = get_group_id(0);
int block_y = get_group_id(1);

// Local ID index (offset within a block)
int local_x = get_local_id(0);
int local_y = get_local_id(1);

// Compute loop bounds
int a_start = A_width * BLOCK_SIZE * block_y;
int a_end   = a_start + A_width - 1;
int b_start = BLOCK_SIZE * block_x;

float running_sum = 0.0f;

// Compute the matrix multiplication result for this output element. Each
// loop iteration processes one block of the matrix.
for (int a = a_start, b = b_start; a <= a_end; a += BLOCK_SIZE, b += (BLOCK_SIZE * B_width))
{
    // Load the matrices to local memory. Note that the (x, y) indices
    // are swapped for A_local and B_local. This affects the reads from
    // A_local and B_local below and result in more efficient hardware.
    //
    // This is actually an optimization that the compiler can perform,
    // but is shown here for illustration purposes.
    A_local[local_y][local_x] = A[a + A_width * local_y + local_x];
    B_local[local_x][local_y] = B[b + B_width * local_y + local_x];

    // Wait for the entire block to be loaded.
    barrier(CLK_LOCAL_MEM_FENCE);

    // Do the dot product accumulation within this block. Fully unroll the loop.
    // As a result of the swap of indices above, memory accesses to
    // A_local and B_local are very efficient because each loop iteration
    // accesses consecutive elements. This can be seen by unrolling the
    // loop and analyzing the regions that are loaded:
    //  A_local[local_y][0..BLOCK_SIZE-1] and
    //  B_local[local_x][0..BLOCK_SIZE-1]

    #pragma unroll
   for (int k = 0; k < BLOCK_SIZE; ++k)
    {
    running_sum += A_local[local_y][k] * B_local[local_x][k];
   // Mutex Implementation
    while(atomic_cmpxchg(&mutex, 0, 1) == 1);
        *num = *num+1; // = num_mul;
        atomic_xchg(&mutex, 0);
    }
   // End Mutex
   // Wait for the block to be fully consumed before loading the next
    // block.
    barrier(CLK_LOCAL_MEM_FENCE);
}

// Store result in matrix C
C[get_global_id(1) * get_global_size(0) + get_global_id(0)] = running_sum;
}
```

When I use the emulator for compiling the program, the compiled done correctly and runs correctly but it takes a long time to finish running which is obvious because of the lock.

When I compiled it using my FPGA board Stratix V, then it won't compiled and it will give me the following Error

> ```
> aoc: OpenCL parser completed successfully.
>   aoc: Optimizing and doing static analysis of code...
>   aoc: Linking with IP library ...
>   Checking if memory usage is larger than 100%
>   Compiler Warning: Vectorized kernel contains loads/stores that cannot        be vectorized. This might reduce performance.
>   aoc: First stage compilation completed successfully.
>   Compiling for FPGA. This process may take a long time, please be patient.
>   Error (293007): Current module quartus_map ended unexpectedly. Verify that you have sufficient memory available to compile your design.
>  Error: Flow compile (for project /home/tanash/Music/matrix_mult_mutex_board_fp_no/bin/matrix_mult/top) was not successful
>  Error: ERROR: Error(s) found while running an executable. See report file(s) for error message(s). Message log indicates which executable was run last.
>  Error (23031): Evaluation of Tcl script /home/tanash/Build/intelFPGA/17.1/quartus/common/tcl/internal/qsh_flow.tcl unsuccessful
>  Error: Quartus Prime Shell was unsuccessful. 4 errors, 2965 warnings
>  Error: Compiler Error, not able to generate hardware
> ```

I am wondering what's wrong with my code and how I can implement Mutex? Is my mutex implementation is wrong?

Comment: Can u use barriers?

Comment: Yes, I can. Is there is a way to use barriers?